# Нужна помощь в графическом разборе слова "соскуча"

Tags: орфография

Помогите произвести графический разбор слова "соскуча"

Answer (score 2):

Для справки.

**[СОСКУЧИТЬ](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/65957/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)** (устар.) -

то же, что соскучиться.

*Соскуча глядеть из окна на грязный переулок, я пошел бродить по всем комнатам.* (Пушкин, Капитанская дочка)

*Соскуча* - деепричастие от глагола (устаревшего) *соскучить* - сов. в., наст. вр., неперех.

Со - приставка,

скуч - корень (с чередованием к/ч),

а - суффикс (деепричастия).

**[О подобных деепричастиях у Розенталя](http://www.sinykova.ru/spravochnik-rozental/styli_xl/)**:

> В парах высунув – высуня (ср. бежать высуня язык), положив – положа
>   (ср. положа руку на сердце), разинув – разиня (ср. слушать разиня
>   рот), скрепив – скрепя (ср. согласиться скрепя сердце), сломив – сломя
>   (ср. броситься сломя голову), спустив – спустя (ср. работать спустя
>   рукава) и т. п. вторые формы устарели и сохраняются лишь в устойчивых
>   фразеологических выражениях. Ср. также устарелый оттенок в формах
>   вспомня, встретя, заметя, наскуча, обнаружа, обратя, оставя, простя,
>   разлюбя, расставя, увидя, услыша и т. п.

Так как "графически" я тут нарисовать не могу, предлагаю аналогичным образом рассмотренное деепричастие "унося":

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Галина**, я часа два назад поставил плюсик за первую редакцию Вашего ответа. Внеся изменения в свой ответ, Вы его только испортили. Ну как можно было написать, что слово "унося" образовано префиксально-суффиксальным способом? Это от какого же слова оно могло быть так образовано?

Comment: Слава, так то ж не я, а сайт! Суффиксальный способ! Щас сотру безобразию!